Sonar Qube report link
Sonar Qube is working but not loading the report. When I'm using Sonar Qube in ADO it returns the following link https://sonarqubeenterprise.pgcloud.com/sonarqube/dashboard?id=*** in the configuration I passed the required param which is SQ project key, but unable to load proper project... Can you help me solving the issue

here is my configuration in ADO
  - script: |
      docker run \
        --rm \
        -e SONAR_HOST_URL="$(sq_host)" \
        -e SONAR_LOGIN="$(sq_token)" \
        -v "${{ parameters.tempDirectory }}:/usr/src" \
        sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli \
        -Dsonar.projectKey="$(sq_project_key)" \
        -Dsonar.sources=/usr/src
    displayName: 'SonarQube Analysis of Artifacts'

